# Excel: How to turn two vertical dimensions into a vertical dimension and a horizontal one

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that roughly looks like this:

```
  col1 col2  col3                        table1
---------------
01| 1   A  value1A
02| 1   B  value1B
03| 1   Z  value1Z
04| 2   Z  value2Z
05| 3   A  value3A
06| 3   B  value3B
07| 3   Z  value3Z
08| 4   A  value4A
09| 4   B  value4B
10| 4   Z  value4Z
11| 5   Z  value5Z
```

And I would like to obtain something like this:

```
      A       B       Z                  table2
 -------------------------
1| value1A value1B value1Z
2|                 value2Z
3| value3A value3B value3Z
4| value4A value4B value4Z
5|                 value5Z
```

Where the formula in cell A1 from table2 computes valueA1 through the values located in cells A1 and B1 from table1 and where the second column in table1 is sometimes only filled with one value (always Z in that case). If not filled with one single value, it'll always be 3 values (A, B and Z).

So far I haven't found anything convenient.

EDIT: as mentioned in the below comments, you should also know that value1Z is actually the sum of value1A and value1B.

EDIT2: I'd rather not use a pivot table. In my very specific case, that is not very suitable.

Comment: Is the sequence 3 1's in a column then 3 2's below so on and also that you have a pattern of A B C repeating in next column, constant?

Comment: That's a good question and the answer is unfortunately no. It turns out that I've actually oversimplified my problem. I'll update my post to make things clearer.

Comment: Further in your table1, Col C 1st value is 'value1A' but in your output table you have shown it as 'valueA1' is this how you want it (interchange last two characters) or it's just a typo error?

Comment: Typo error. I just corrected it, along with the addition of more details about my issue.

Comment: Are you OK with the gaps in between as shown in your Table2 or you expect each column to be contiguous range?

Comment: Yes those gaps are normal. The Z value is actually the sum of A and B. And sometimes I only have the total, sometimes I also have the different elements of the sum.

Comment: Are your `value1Z` indeed numbers, or are they text?

Comment: value1Z is a number while 1 and Z are not.

Comment: What's Row 3 C Value1Z in that case? is there a C in your data or it's also supposed to be 'Z'?

Comment: Typo again. I'm really sorry about that.

Comment: "I'd rather not use a pivot table. In my very specific case, that is not very suitable." - what is the exact problem with it? What else do you expect? Formula - surely would be far more complicated and it's a pain to maintain. Macro - this isn't a free code writing service, and also it's difficult to modify (somebody else's code).

Comment: I will need to insert rows and/or to modify formulas within some cells in order for me to make some manual adjustments. Do you think I could do that with a pivot table?

Answer (score 2):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub MAIN2()
    Dim r As Range, v, numb, letr
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Columns(1).SpecialCells(2).Copy Cells(2, 4)
    Columns(4).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Columns(2).SpecialCells(2).Copy Cells(2, 5)
    Columns(5).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    Set r = Columns(5).SpecialCells(2)
    r.Copy
    Cells(1, 5).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    r.Clear

    For Each r In Columns(3).SpecialCells(2)
        v = r.Value
        numb = r.Offset(0, -2).Value
        lett = r.Offset(0, -1).Value

        For i = 2 To Rows.Count
            If Cells(i, 4) = numb Then Exit For
        Next i
        For j = 5 To Columns.Count
            If Cells(1, j) = lett Then Exit For
        Next j

        Cells(i, j) = v
    Next r

End Sub
```

[image]

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply! I'm afraid you've used the previous version of my problem when there was still a typo in it: there is no C in column B, it should be a Z. Can you modify your code accordingly?

Comment: @Guillaume  The code will be the same...............but I will update the picture.

Comment: @Guillaume  Picture update complete

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a pivot table.

Edit: here's a worked example. Not sure why this doesn't suit your requirement? https://excel.solutions/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Guillaume.xlsx

You can easily change the column order in pivot tables by manually adjusting, or by using custom lists.

Comment: please elaborate it more, currently it more looks like a comment and not an answer. If OP would be familiar with pivot tables, he wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: That's indeed a possible solution but not a convenient one in my case. For instance, I cannot order the columns to my liking when using pivot tables (I might be wrong about that but I don't think so). I'd rather a more flexible solution with formulas in each cell.

Comment: @Guillaume You can order columns and rows in pivot table, just by drag and drop (see "set custom sort options" [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-data-in-a-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-E41F7107-B92D-44EF-861F-24430830450A?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)). Also this is not a requirement in your question. Please edit your question and include everything relevant, otherwise people will just waste their time suggesting solutions which are "not convenient" for you.

Comment: Thank you Máté. I've edited my question. Problem is, it is sometimes after you get replies that you realize how "unprecise" your question is :)

Comment: I've added an example pivot solution. Not sure why this doesn't match your requirement?

Comment: Hi Olly. It does, thank you for that. As explained above, I'm not a huge fan of pivot tables in that context because they seem less flexible to me. I was wrong about the order of the columns but if I for instance want to insert rows into my pivot table or change the formula within a single cell, things get pretty complicated...